# PHP - capture the username from a database based on a echo result on to another page

Tags: php, mysql, database, echo

I have a search engine which displays a list of ads, i was wondering how i would capture the username from a result that a user clicks on (using a database query, PDO)

so far i have this but am not sure how to make it relate to the exact result that a user clicks on:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=:username";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();
$row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$email1 = $row['email'];
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't seem to be relevant to what you're trying to do in any way. All you're doing is finding a user's email based on his username.

Comment: sorry i meant to say username in my description not ID - have corrected it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in theory your ad has a unique ID doesnt it? As part of your click string such as http://mysite.com/adclick.php?adid=1 it knows to go to the ad ID one url on redirect and you can then increment/store any uses etc.

Comment: currently, the results are displayed as an echo output in a table and they dont have unique ids as they cannot be currently clicked

Comment: Then it seems you have a design flaw.